# Capybara + RSpec, spec/features dir being ignored by the rspec . command?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using the new Capybara DSL with rspec following the short guideline located [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara)
And the tests added to the `spec/features` directory run well *alone*, ie.

`rails_project$ rspec spec/features/my_first_feature.rb`

However the `spec/features` directory is **totally ignored** when I try to run the tests for the entire `spec/` directory like this:

`rails_project$ rspec .`

There is no mention in the guide about how to include this directory (or other directory) to accomplish this *inclusion* that I desire. I really need this for continuous integration of my project.

Can anybody please tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to make sure all of your specs end in`_spec.rb`.

Change the filename to `spec/features/my_first_feature_spec.rb`

This is how I do it:

```
rspec spec
```

You may also want to use `guard-rspec`, which gives you better control.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! How could I not remember that! I feel so dumb now.
Anyways, thanks once more, I owe you one.

Comment: It's part of being human. After you do the same thing about 3 times you'll remember it.

Comment: It seems now you need to `require 'capybara/rspec'` in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` if you are using feature specs in capybara version > 2.x